# Pointing to subdomains with Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, subdomain

I want both www.domain.ie and domain.ie to point to domain.herokuapp.com

I want secure.domain.ie to point to a third party booking engine.

I've run the following command:

```
heroku domains:add www.tankardstown.ie
```

Here is what my DNS setup looks like

[image]

The www.domain.ie and domain.ie redirects are working fine. The problem is with the secure.domain.ie. Currently, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Ignore my answer, sorry I misread your question. I think the the *.domain is taking precedence. Can you redirect at the application level (not the dns level)?

Comment: Not sure how to do that.....

Comment: I don't think it takes precedence (from own experiences), but would say it might be an issue of DNS caching. Your DNS changes might not have been propagated to all relevant DNS servers before you pointed your browser to the `secure.domain.ie` domain. Try waiting up to 24 hours and flushing your browser's DNS cache. Great website by the way! Really nice design and typography.

Comment: No the booking engine is hosted elsewhere.

Comment: [This screenshot](http://grab.by/lA4S) is what I see. So your DNS setup seems correct, you just need to clear your browser's DNS cache and /(or?) your computer's DNS cache.

Comment: Ok, so you reckon I just gotta sit tight for a few hours? Answer the question and I'll give you the points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be ok:

```
$ dig +noall +answer secure.tankardstown.ie
secure.tankardstown.ie. 86395   IN  A   82.195.138.28
```

probably just a DNS propagation delay?

Comment: She's still not live. It's been almost 36 hours since I changed the settings. It looks like there's some other problem?

Comment: do you get the same dig response?

Comment: I think it was a problem with the third party booking engine. She's working now. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue whilst looking for something else, but thought I'd better answer this question for other weary travellers...

Looks this issue was because the domain was not added correctly to Heroku.
The OP only added 'www.' but should have added a wildcard domain or 'secure.' as a subdomain.

**Actual Solution:**

OP should have run:

```
heroku domains:add *.tankardstown.ie
```

Heroku has more information here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-wildcard-domain